# Interface particular properties

Tags: c#, interface

How to solve this problem about interfaces? I think I need this variable (and some others)in this especific class.

```
public interface Action
{
    void execute();
}

public A:Action
{ 
    public int misteriousNumber;  

    void execute()
    {
         int iUseMisteriousNumber = misteriousNumber;
    }   
}

public B:Action
{ 
    void execute()
    {
       //I use nothing.
    }   
}

//Some Class...
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach(Action action in SecretRepositoryOfTheActions.actions)
    {
        if(action is A)
            (SomeTypeOfCasting to A)action.misteriousNumber=13;            
       action.execute();
    }
}
```

Just the 'A' class have this property not other Action classes what to use to access it (casting, not interfaces other implementation)?

Comment: What do your want to achieve? Be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to cast it, first check the type with [`is`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

```
 foreach(Action action in SecretRepositoryOfTheActions.actions)
 {
     if(action is A)
         ((A) action).misteriousNumber = 13;   
      action.execute();
 }
```

If you only wanted to process `A`-objects (which doesn't seem to be the case):

```
 foreach(A a in SecretRepositoryOfTheActions.actions.OfType<A>())
 {
     a.misteriousNumber = 13;   
     a.execute();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, new in C# :)